# Struts2 tag <s:text> I need to lower case the string returned

Tags: struts2

So I have a tag like this

```
<s:text name="furniture_logs" />
```

Where s is defined:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/struts-tags.tld"%>
```

and "furniture_logs" is a key from the database (returnes a string) . I want to show the lower case of this string, what can I do ?  I am new to Struts2 and i didnt find any reference for that.

Comment: Why are you using a uri like that? Why not use the normal one? Did you extract the tld, and if so, why?!

Answer (score 3):

The `<s:text>` tag is for rendering a I18n text messages. If you really want to use it then you could try calling `getText` method and `toLowerCase` in `<s:property>` tag like that:

```
<s:property value="getText('furniture_logs').toLowerCase()"/>
```

Struts2 uses OGNL that means you can call Java methods inside Struts2 tags. Read about OGNL http://commons.apache.org/ognl/.

**Update**
If using `<s:text>` tag is a must to you, then use `var` attribute of it.

```
<s:text var="flogs" name="furniture_logs"/>
<s:property value="#flogs.toLowerCase()"/>
```

Comment: I have to use <s:text /> as requirement . And  <s:text value="getText('furniture_logs').toLowerCase()"/> does not give desired output...

Comment: <s:property> is not fine for me as 'furniture_logs' is not defined in my action, but rather it is taken directly from database through some mappings.... so <s:text/> is a must use

Comment: @Madrugada What kind of "requirement" is that? The *requirement* its to show a lowercase version of an I18n string from the db.